# Error Detection Distance of Residue Codes

Tags: coding-theory, encoding-scheme

Given a residue code representing a number `N` with the tuple `(N, R(N))`where R(N) equals `N mod A`.

What is the error detection distance of a certain check base `A`? In other words, how many bits can be flipped but still detect an error?

Edit: 
I would think the minimum distance is 2 for any base. Consider a base A > 2. If `N` equals 1, R(N) also equals 1. If we now look for for N+1 = 2, R(N) equals 2. The Hamming distance between those residue tuples is `HD((1, 1), (2, 2)) = 2`, which cannot be better.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, and where have you failed? We're not here to do your homework, we're here to help you do it on your own.

Comment: @YuvalFilmusI updated my question with thoughts of mine.

Comment: If A is a power of two then the minimum distance is 1. For example A = 4, N = 1 and N = 5, R(N) = 1 in either case.

Comment: HD((1,1), (2,2)) = 4. There are four single bit changes. Check N = 2 and N = 3 instead.

Comment: If no power of two is divisible by A, then a single bit change in N creates at least a single bit change in R(N), so minimum distance ≥ 2. On the other hand, R(0) = 0, R(1) = 1, so the minimum is achievable.

Comment: Right, so a residue code in best case can only protect against 2 bit flips. Not against more flips. `HD((1,1), (2,2)) = 4` right. The correct example would be N= 0 and N=1 or 2 and 3.

Comment: Have you answered your own question?  We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.  (continued)

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.